# Do I have to install the certificate before accessing an https url?

Tags: certificate, ca

I'm not clear about the authorization of certificate: a website has been associated with a certificate, say https://test.mysite.com. Do I have to install the certificate on my computer before access this url?

Another question is: every certificate is issued by a CA. If I have trusted a CA before by "installing" a cerficiate, will I trust the all the following certificates issued by the same CA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the library or browser you are using to access to the URL but, if the certificate is issued by a trusted CA (one that your library or browser already trusts), the web site's certificate does not need to be installed before accessing the site.

If the CA is not trusted, there are two options. One is to trust the certificate. Browsing to the page will usually open a dialog where the user can choose to trust the certificate, for example. The second is to add the CA to the list of trusted CAs. On Windows, this is done by adding the CA's certificate to the "Trusted Root Authorities" certificate store. The latter case means any other certificate issued by the CA will also be trusted.